# Physics exam about work had me confused

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, work

*The velocity of a particle moving along the x axis changes from vi to vf. For which values of vi and vf is the total
work done on the particle positive?*

A. vi = −5 m/s and vf = 2 m/s

B. vi = 5 m/s and vf = −2 m/s

C. vi = 5 m/s and vf = 2 m/s

D. vi = −5 m/s and vf = −2 m/s

E. vi = −2 m/s and vf = −5 m/s

**The answer is given as E**

*A force F=4i+3j-5k N acts on a mass of 2 kg as it moves in the x direction at a speed of 7 m/s. What is the rate at which the force is doing work?*

A. 60 W

B. 35 W

C. 28 W

D. 14 W

E. 8.8 W

**Now the answer is given as C**

This confused me greatly as I solved this question with 2 methods and the answer only comes up as 28W if I take the work done on the k direction as negative which I can't wrap my head around. Just like in the first question, shouldn't the work done be positive even though if the direction is negative as I just applied 5N of force on an object at rest (k component). And yet the first question has a similar approach and the correct answer is one that basically accelerates the object in that same direction (which is negative). Please someone help me understand this.

Comment: Try thinking of the difference between velocity and speed; the first is a vector and the second is a scalar; we can think of work likewise, work can be either negative or positive (but it's not a vector) or we can take its absolute magnitude. Which is right depends on the question being asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Work done is equal to change in kinetic energy

work done = $\frac 12 m v^2_{\rm f} - \frac 12 m v^2_{\rm i}$ so for the work done to be positive you must have $v^2_{\rm f} > v^2_{\rm i}$ and only option **E** satisfies that condition.

power = $\vec F \cdot \vec v \Rightarrow (4 \hat i + 3 \hat j -5 \hat k)\cdot 7 \hat i = 28 \,\rm W$ which is option **C**.

Comment: so in the second question, do the j and k components not matter at all?

Comment: @MehmetKaanÖzkan Correct, remembering that work done is force times displacement along the line of action of the force.

Comment: @MehmetKaanÖzkan Note that $\hat{j} \cdot \hat{i} = \hat{k} \cdot \hat{i} = 0$.  The dot product of perpendicular vectors is 0.